# Dhp L2TP reservation on cisco 1921

Tags: dhcp, l2tp

I use a Cisco 1921 as L2TP server.
(I don't want to use RADIUS authentication.)
Please is someone can tell me how is it possible to do IP reservation, using client identification?
I have tried dhcp pool commands *client-identifier* or *client-name*, without result.
Here is a debug of dhcp server event:

> Aug 3 11:31:08.682: DHCPD: IP address change on interface Virtual-Access2.2
> Aug  3 11:31:09.034: DHCPD: allocate request for client cisco102 on Virtual-Access2.2.
> Aug  3 11:31:09.034: DHCPD: Pool POOL10252 specified.
> Aug  3 11:31:09.034: DHCPD: Interface Virtual-Access2.2 is not associated with any VRF.
> Aug  3 11:31:09.038: DHCPD: found pool POOL10252 for client cisco102.
> Aug  3 11:31:09.042: DHCPD: Adding binding to radix tree (10.250.252.2)
> Aug  3 11:31:09.042: DHCPD: Adding binding to hash tree
> Aug  3 11:31:09.046: DHCPD: assigned IP address 10.250.252.2 to client 6369.7363.6f31.3032.

Can someone help me please?
Thanks in advance.
Jimmy C

Comment: If the client is using BOOTP, then you need to use the `hardware-address`. FYI, it is time to replace that hardware because the software updates sopped three years ago, and it will be completely EoL next month.

Comment: Hi Ron,
@RonMaupin
Thanks for your reply.   
Unfortunately I can't use the "hardware-address" command because when I log the DHCP process the router receive an adress like   
'6170.6172.616e.4067.726f.7570.656c.626d.2e63.6f6d'  witch is not accepted.  
About the Cisco 1921, this a router used for lab & test, but the issue is the same on more recent appliances.